# How to Save the system state in Java and resume the system when I recompile the project?

Tags: java, file, memory-management, software-design

I have a system in Java where different classes stores different information. There is a main class where the user will input the information of these classes and make them interact with each other. After the user is done, he will exit the system. The Next time the user recompile the project, all the previously entered data should be there. The user can use that same data or add more information.

So Simply, How to pause/save the system on close and resume it when I execute it again?
PS. I can't use Database in this. It must be something else.

Comment: Do you literally mean recompile? That is, change the program, and run a new version? If so, will the structure of data change, or just the operations that manipulate that data?

Comment: No. The Program will NOT change. Just re-executed. Like at the beginning, it will check if there's some old data saved somewhere (NOT DB), then it will retrieve that data and store it in the appropriate position(An ArrayList of objects)

Comment: What do you consider a database versus not a database? Does that mean you can’t have another process like a database server running independently of this program? What about one of the many lightweight, in-process databases? The simplest thing for java would be to make your data structures serializable and to write it to a file with Java’s builtin serialization.

Comment: That is exactly what I need. But data serialization is a little complex and not so functional. Can you recommend any other?

Comment: In general, storing data is not simple. Java's serialization is robust and handles a lot of corner cases, but if you don't do anything strange with your data classes, using it can be as simple as making each data class implement the `Serializable` interface and writing and reading to a file using an `ObjectOutputStream` or `ObjectInputStream`. If you need help, show how far you've gotten with your code, and ask a specific question when you encounter a problem.

Answer (score 2):

> The Next time the user recompile the project

Users dont recompile projects. They just run your app.

You keep saying 'not DB', so, then, the answer is trivially: **impossible**.

A database, by definition, persists some data, hence the name: It's a base of data. If that's off the table, you're out of luck and what you want is not possible.

Perhaps you are careless in your wording there as well and all you mean is perhaps:

#### *I do not want to bother with forcing the user to install a database*

Okay, then, don't. Use an in-process database, such as [h2](https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html). The user doesn't know an SQL-based database system is involved, all they see is a file appear. No extra processes are launched.

#### *I hate SQL*

Okay, then, don't. There are tools out there that turn an entire object structure into a bag o bytes which you can then save to a file, for example [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) which can turn one object (which can contain all the relevant user data if you want) into JSON data, which you can then save to a file, and restore later. Of course, if someone trips over a powercable halfway through writing it, the file is corrupted. There are ways to fix that (save to `.tmp`, then move it into place, as that's usually atomic), but you're sort of committed to re-inventing the wheel here, due to your insistence you don't want databases.

### *I just want to save the entire system state*

You can't. Not how java works.

### *Can't I do it with zero dependencies?*

There's java's built in serialization system, which sucks, has a list of caveats as long as my leg on how to use it, and is more or less disliked by the maintainers of the java platform itself. This is not the way to go. It also still won't 'save the entire system state', it just saves one object, and does a much worse job at this than e.g. jackson.

Comment: Yeah. By Database, I actually meant MySQL or any other external Database system. But the file system that you are suggesting sounds interesting. Is it possible to write and read the objects from this "specific" file then load them into the system? What External libraries would I need other than Jackson can you please recommend?

Comment: 'h2' starts no servers and has no binaries, it's just.. a jar. It ends up making 1 file. You 'write' to the file with SQL, and read from it in the same way. You need nothing except h2 to use it, see h2's website for more info. Same goes for jackson: Jackson can turn objects into strings, and the core java libraries will trivially let you write that to a file. See the API of java.nio.file.Files for that part.